# apache HttpClient: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated. The code I am using is as follows:

```
        HttpResponse targetResponse = getHttpClient(true).execute(post,
                localContext);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                targetResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = new String();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.contains("attr1") && !line.contains("attr2"))
                continue;
            String[] splits = line.split(": ");
            if (splits[0].contains("attr1")) {
                attr1 = splits[1].trim();
            } else {
                attr2 = splits[1].trim();
            }

            if (attr1 != null && attr2 != null)
                break;
        }
```

My understanding is that as soon as I do the targetResponse.getEntity() the entity should be consumed. Do I need to make an explicit call EntityUtils.consume() as well?

Comment: Try closing the BufferedReader to close the entity's InputStream which consumes the entity.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably utilize an EntityUtils.consume() to consume any remaining content in the stream if you have not already done so.

Or take @dnault's suggestion and close the stream.